# Blocking ports without any firewall?

Tags: windows, port

I want to close ports on my windows computer without using any firewall or similar software? Also i only want to open them when i use an explicit command. I didnt tried anything because i have no idea how to do this. i searched SU but only found questions about doing it with a firewall software but i dont want a 3rd party software again.

i hope what i try to do is possible and i will get an answer here. thank you

Comment: Use your router?

Answer (score 1):

First: no, because blocking packets according to some rules is exactly what a firewall *does*. Even if you did it using a built-in function, that would *still* be called a firewall. (Or a packet filter, or a network ACL.)

Which also means that a "firewall" doesn't have to be third-party software. **Windows has had a built-in firewall for many releases.** Though on Windows XP it only filtered incoming connections – just run `firewall.cpl` – but the Windows 7 version can set up rules in both directions (configured through the `wf.msc` console).

(Even going back to NT 4.0, you could find a "port-based filtering" option – a stateless firewall – deep inside TCP/IP settings.)

Though it doesn't have to be done directly on your computer; if it's stationary, the same kind of firewall rules could often be added to a router or a switch. It all depends on who/what you're protecting from.

Answer (score 0):

You can shutdown the servers. A script could identify and kill processes or you could do it manually killing the process with the taskkill command.(not really blocking a port and btw google suggests that blocking a port is terminology associated with firewalls, i'm not sure what else, maybe NAT routers)

I see that as of writing you didn't specify a windows version. And that's fine your question works as a theoretical one too.

(Security researcher or hobbyist) Volker Birk wrote a program that shuts down servers on Windows XP

[http://www.dingens.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20081102100933/http://www.dingens.org/)

I'm not aware of one for Windows 7

But he has provided the source code so a C programmer could adapt it.

I haven't tried Volker Birk's 'shutdown windows servers' program, but with a program that shuts down windows servers, you would find functionality is less with servers shutdown e.g. no file sharing.

If you leave the servers running and block it from the computer that might always count as a firewall. 3rd party or not.